# "Local free"ness in vector bundles and projective modules

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

[Swan's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan%27s_theorem) tells us that (real) vector bundles on $X$ are the same as finitely-generated projective modules over $C(X)$ (continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $X$. And vector bundles are thought of as locally free sheaves.

There's also a local freeness condition for modules over any commutative ring $R$. An $R$-module $P$ is **locally free** if the localization $P_\mathfrak{m} := R_\mathfrak{m} \otimes_R P$ is free as a $R_\mathfrak{m}$-module for every $\mathfrak{m} \in \text{MaxSpec}(R)$.

**Theorem:** *If $P$ is a finitely-presented $R$-module, then $P$ is locally free iff $P$ is projective.*

So "locally free" sheaf is the same as "locally free" module (except you need some kind of finite presentation condition). What does this have to do with trivializations? Does a trivialization of a vector bundle correspond to a localization of its module of global sections?

More specifically: a trivialization of a bundle $E$ is an open set $U$ over which the bundle is a Cartesian product $U\times \mathbb{R}^k$. Does this somehow correspond to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $C(X)$ so that $\Gamma(E)_\mathfrak{m}$ is a free module?

Comment: The definition of locally free is not correct (see everywhere for the correct definition).

Comment: @Martin: The theorem I wrote down *is* correct though.

Comment: Also: the terminology "locally free" is straight from Eisenbud.

Answer (score 1):

A locally free sheaf is only the same as a locally free module over an affine scheme/variety.

There's no finite presentation condition required.

A trivialization of a vector bundle is a cover of your space by Zariski open sets such that the restriction of your bundle to each open set in the cover is isomorphic to the trivial vector bundle (of the same rank).

The connection with locally free sheaves, is that any vector bundle is determined by its sheaf of sections, and vice versa. For a trivial vector bundle $U\times K^n$ over $U$ ($K$ is a field), a section $U\rightarrow U\times K^n$ is the same as giving an $n$-tuple of functions $(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\in\mathcal{O}_U(U)^n$, so for trivial vector bundles, its sheaf of sections is just the free sheaf of rank $n$. Hence, any trivialization of a vector bundle corresponds to a trivialization of its sheaf of sections (ie, an open cover where on each open set the sheaf of sections is actually free). In terms of commutative algebra, if the base space was affine, and you choose a trivialization by affine open sets, then yes the restriction of your sheaf of sections to each affine open in the trivialization, corresponding to a localization of the corresponding locally free module, will give you actually a free sheaf, corresponding to a free module.

Comment: You're localizing at ideals though, which are points. Trivializations are over open sets.

Comment: The stalk at a point being free is the same as saying that the sheaf is free in an open neighborhood of the point. Recall that the definition of the stalk of a sheaf at a point is the direct limit of its sections over open neighborhoods of the point, and being free is to say that there exist a basis of sections, so at least when the rank is finite, for each element of your basis in the stalk, it's defined over some neighborhood. If the rank is finite, you can take the finite intersection of the open neighborhoods where each section is defined, and get an open nbhd where your sheaf is free.

Comment: In the infinite rank case, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_free_sheaf it seems that your definition of locally free doesn't imply the usual definition (that there exists an open cover trivializing the sheaf).

Comment: What's amazing, to me at least, is that local freeness is local in the Zariski topology. This implies, that for a holomorphic vector bundle on a compact Riemann surface, you need only remove finitely many points from the Riemann surface to get an open set over which the vector bundle is trivial.

Comment: Does this make sense? If there's something about my answer you don't understand I'd be happy to expand on it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the connecting between vector bundles and locally free sheaves, but I want to know more about projective modules. Those are formed by looking at global sections of a vector bundle. If the base space is compact and hausdorff, then the global sections module is finitely-generated and projective.

So you're saying that localizing $\Gamma(E)$ at a maximal ideal of $C(X)$ corresponds to looking at the stalk of the sheaf of sections?

Comment: If the base is affine, then the localization of the module of global sections at a maximal ideal of your ring of functions is precisely the stalk of the sheaf of sections at the point corresponding to the maximal ideal. If the base is not affine, then if you pick an affine nbhd $U$ of a point corresponding to a maximal ideal $m$, then the stalk of the sheaf of sections of your vector bundle at $m$ is precisely the localization of the module of sections over $U$, at the ideal $m$.

Comment: The affineness is important, since you can look at any locally free sheaves/vector bundles on say, the Riemann sphere (ie, $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$), where the module of global sections is then just $\mathbb{C}^n$ (since the ring of holomorphic functions on the Riemann sphere consist only of the constant functions)